# Can Diplomacy be useful in flashpoints?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've played through several Flashpoints by now and I've noticed that there are usually several places where having a particular crew skill trained sufficiently can unlock a bonus or a shortcut -- slicing the controls to an elevator, archaeology can sometimes get machinery in old ruins to work and open a door, etc.

Are there similar points where Diplomacy is helpful? IE, conversation options that only arise if your Diplomacy skill is high enough and let you defuse a situation without violence ensuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen biochem, slicing and scavenging (or maybe it was cybertech, not sure) used so far.  Usually nothing groundbreaking so you shouldn't swear over that, it's just nice little things here and there like access to an extra small chest to open, or maybe opening a locked door to bypass a group of enemies, etc. Nothing major (they don't want groups looking for members that have specific skills)

Comment: Do you remember where did you see biochem?

Comment: I think it was in Hammer station. There is a box you open with biochem that has some stims inside, and with those stims you can pass through a gas filled passageway to a room with a chest (but there are a couple of elites there on the way)

Comment: Looks like the answer is no. Thanks for helping me check, at least - accepting this one.

Answer (score 2):

In general, only **Gathering** skills allow interaction with objects in the world. These are: Slicing, Scavenging, Bioanalysis, and Archaeology.

Mission skills like Diplomacy or Investigation do not have interactive nodes of this sort, nor do crafting skills like Biochem or Cybertech.

Answer (score 1):

I do have Diplomacy and I haven't noticed anything like that in any of the Flashpoints I played so far.

One difference between the skills you mentioned that unlock something and Diplomacy is that Diplomacy is a Mission skill, while the other two are Crafting skills. That being said, I didn't use my Crafting skill, Biochem, in any Flashpoint so far either.